# Nginx with openssl build error CentOS 7 - "basename: missing operand"

Tags: nginx, build, openssl, centos

fighting with the issue, trying to build the Nginx from source,

CentOS 7 on DigitalOcean VM,

tried with openssl-1.1.1e, and openssl-1.1.1d,

```
[root@digocean nginx-1.17.9]# make
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
install libssl.a -> /root/openssl-1.1.1e/.openssl/lib/libssl.a
basename: missing operand
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
make[2]: *** [install_dev] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/openssl-1.1.1e'
make[1]: *** [/root/openssl-1.1.1e/.openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/nginx-1.17.9'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

the ./configure is successful.

Please help, first time I face this!

Thank you!!

Comment: Maybe have a look at [NGINX-MOD](https://www.getpagespeed.com/nginx-mod-a-better-faster-nginx-build) which already built with latest OpenSSL, and thus supports TLS 1.3, and has features beyond that. Although a commercial thing :) but will save you hours of work and prevent polluting production server with compilation software (security risk of its own)

Comment: Alternatively consider to use the meanwhile available `openssl11-devel` RPM package from EPEL 7 rather building OpenSSL yourself, given it needs security updates somewhen, too.

Answer (score 0):

[FEDORA-EPEL-2020-1dc525ea93](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-EPEL-2020-1dc525ea93) provides meanwhile Nginx 1.16 linked against OpenSSL 1.1, which should be pretty much what you're looking for.